# html files don't load properly in any browser

Tags: html, css

I've been following along to examples from MDN and an online course for a few days. Out of no where, my html files won't load correctly in any browser I use(Firefox, Chrome, IE, Edge). Most or all of the body content doesn't show up.

This problem started last night. Any html files I created before last night work just fine.

I used Codepen to try and see if my code is just totally wrong. The pages displayed just fine in Codepen, so now I am extra confused.

I use Sublime Text 2 if that matters.

I would appreciate any advice or suggestions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Photo Blog</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="photos.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Look at the Photos!</p>
        <img src=">http://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8450/8026519634_f33f3724ea_b.jpg"> 
        <img src=">http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7218/7209301894_c99d3a33c2_h.jpg"> 
        <img src=">http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7231/6947093326_df216540ff_b.jpg"> 
        <img src=">http://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8788/17367410309_78abb9e5b6_b.jpg"> 
        <img src=">http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5814/20700286354_762c19bd3b_b.jpg"> 
        <img src=">http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5647/21137202535_404bf25729_b.jpg"> 
        <img src=">http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5588/14991687545_5c8e1a2e86_b.jpg"> 
        <img src=">http://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3888/14878097108_5997041006_b.jpg"> 
        <img src=">http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7579/15482110477_0b0e9e5421_b.jpg">
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
img{
    width: 30%;
    float:left;
    margin: 1.66%;
}

p{
    font-family: Raleway;
    margin-left: 1.66%
    font-size: 23 px;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
    width: 30%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Remove the `>` at the start of your `src` attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Photo Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="photos.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
    <p>Look at the Photos!</p>


<img src="http://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8450/8026519634_f33f3724ea_b.jpg"> 
<img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7218/7209301894_c99d3a33c2_h.jpg"> 
<img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7231/6947093326_df216540ff_b.jpg"> 

<img src="http://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8788/17367410309_78abb9e5b6_b.jpg"> 
<img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5814/20700286354_762c19bd3b_b.jpg"> 
<img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5647/21137202535_404bf25729_b.jpg"> 

<img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5588/14991687545_5c8e1a2e86_b.jpg"> 
<img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3888/14878097108_5997041006_b.jpg"> 
<img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7579/15482110477_0b0e9e5421_b.jpg">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Jeez! Thank  you for pointing that out. I need to pay attention.